# Sleep button is not active in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, sleep

I updated my Intel HD 3000 graphics drivers and the sleep button is not active any more. I did a restart but it's not working. Under `msinfo32` I have graphic driver details. I have both Intel HD 3000, and AMD Radeon excreate graphics. My laptop is HP Pavilion dv6 with i7 2nd gen, 8GB RAM.

Every time I close the lid to sleep my laptop it's going into the hibernate mode.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is try rolling back your drivers.

Answer (score 0):

May be update and reinstall new graphics driver change your power option of OS.

You can easilly adjust your power plan:

1. Open Power Options by clicking the **Start**, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **System and Security**, and then clicking **Power Options**.
2. click **Change plan** settings.
3. choose the display and sleep settings that you want to use when your computer is running on battery (if applicable) and when it's plugged in.

---

**EDIT** based on comments:

Sorry for misleads! Now I check what is relation of graphics driver and Windows sleep option. I think your laptop is not fully supported new version of this driver. I offer to install old version of it!

[Here is same issue.](https://communities.intel.com/thread/24777) I hope it helps!

Comment: i don't know weather my question misleads or not my problem is not , how to change power options. my problem is sleep option is not active and it is not showing in menu. only hibernate,lock,restart,switch user are active.